# incorrect time display

Tags: bug, timestamps

Unfortunately I don't have a screenshot for this and I don't know how to reproduce it.

Right after I'd posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/396164), I saw it display "answered 3 mins ago". It didn't feel at all as if that much time had passed, so I refreshed the page, and indeed it then said "answered 1 min ago", as expected.

Comment: Were you travelling near the speed of light at the time?

Comment: maybe your computer time is a little out of sync with the StackTime....

Comment: This seems similar to: [Wrong timing for comment editing blocking?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9516/wrong-timing-for-comment-editing-blocking)

Comment: @draks: Thanks -- this actually alerted me to the fact that I'd inadvertently turned off the automatic time synchronization on my computer :-)